# How can I get N results with a condition and M results with another condition in mongodb

Tags: php, mongodb

Sorry this sounds like a silly question but I'm new with mongoDB and I could not find a solution.

I want to get a determinate number (n) of "premium" objects from a collection and another determinate quantity (m) of elements which are no "premium". Both kind of elements are stored in the same collection and they have a boolean field called "premium". They are also geolocated (2d indexed array) and I wanted to get them ordered by distance and then by premium/not premium (in this order of importance).

Don't Know if I am missing something and sorry to disturb.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you seen the "limit(X)" description?  It sounds like what you want.  http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.limit/

Comment: Hello Asya, Thank you for your answer.Yes, but the thing is I don't know how to make the two diferent querries in one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not make two queries in one. You will have to run two queries and use limit for each, and then combine them in your applications.

Alternatively, you run one query without the predicate of "premium" and "non-premium" and split in your application. You might have to overestimate the number of items though so that you have enough premium and non-premium documents in your result.

As you're sorting by distance, I would find it very unlikely that unless you have to documents with the exact same location, you will have two documents that have the same distance any way, so the secondary sorting on "premium" is unlikely to be necessary.

Comment: Thanks Derick. That's what i thought. All premium places should apear first due to requirements an then non-premium ones but both groups ordered by distance. Anyway your answer solves the issue. I thought it could be done in one.